# Does Fallout 4 misgender your character?

Tags: fallout-4

I play as a female character and a relatively significant amount of times (roughly once every 4-10 hours of gameplay) Some character will refer to my character with male pronouns (he/his). Has any one else had this experience of being misgendered by NPCs?

Update: just wanted to add that I play on a ps4

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. May I suggest taking out [tour]? Your question seems more like a conversation starter, rather than a problem to be solved, and as such may be considered to be off-topic.

Comment: @DJPirtu It seems straight forward enough to me.  "does fallout 4 misgender your character?" and "Has any one else had this experience of being misgendered by NPCs?" are both yes/no questions.  Not a lot of conversation necessary, just a screencap or link to a quotation page on the wiki for proof.  I normally make a female sniper/melee type as my second character, so if no one else answers I'll be able to eventually.

Comment: @gatherer818 I agree with you on the first. Altough the asker has already answered that question. The latter is _technicly_ a yes/no question, but is in a form of a form of a usual conversation opener, why I suggested reviewing the tour to make sure the asker is aware of how our site operates. Also, [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask] are worth looking over.

Comment: @DJPirtu feel free to make an edit if you feel it'll make the question clearer, I personally can't see any issue with it.

Comment: I've put this question on hold, as your question is just asking for other people who have experience the same bug, which is not a good fit for our site.

Comment: FWIW: I'm playing a female character, with over 150 hours in this playthrough, and I'm pretty sure I've never had any NPCs refer to her with masculine pronouns.

Comment: Yeah, really all I want is a yes/no.

Comment: I don't think I've had this happen either. If you can note a specific example of it happening, that would pretty much be an answer.

Comment: It definitely happened to me most during the USS Constitution quest..

Comment: I'm not sure the USS Constitution quest is good reference point. The characters involved in that quest are lunatics. Has it happened elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, at least half a dozen NPCs have misgendered me. The robots dialog was just particularly memorable.

Comment: In what context/phrasing is this happening? I think the only time I've had hit happen now is when someone referred to my female character as "sir". But that's a person who would naturally be subordinate to me within a pseudo-military organization.

Comment: I've had one Vault 81 security NPC commenting on my character (a burly, blonde, blue-eyed guy with quite a nice moustache) along the lines of "You're quite a strong woman.", so the game definitively has bugs like that. It's most likely just switched conditional statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
It happens to my female character, quite often. My friends mentioned such bugs, too.

Comment: I've played through the game multiple times, including twice as a female, and never had this happen even once. Without a single reproducible example, I'm going to have to question the claim that this happens "quite often".

Comment: I understand you. But, I don't think I can go back all the way to find those particular scenes where the said error occurs. I'm, maybe, one of those rare cases. I even chanced upon this page only while googling **my problem**. Perhaps, you have a better update installed.

Comment: which platform do you use?

Comment: @Veg Windows 10. What about you?

Comment: I can confirm that this also happens to my female character.